# rails loop with infinite values to set background color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having following loop

I have all datas in `@clients`

```
[1,2,3,4,5].each { |rows|
    if rows % 2 == 0
        sheet1.row(rows).default_format = bg_color1
    else
        sheet1.row(rows).default_format = bg_color2
    end
}
```

But i have more than 100 rows. How do i count `@clients` and use it in each loop as above

Comment: You can try this method: @clients.each_with_index do |client, i|

Comment: @hedgesky works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
@clients.each_with_index { |rows,i|
    if i % 2 == 0
        sheet1.row(i).default_format = bg_color1
    else
        sheet1.row(i).default_format = bg_color2
    end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@clients.each_with_index do |client, index|
  if index % 2 == 0
      sheet1.row(index+1).default_format = bg_color1
  else
      sheet1.row(index+1).default_format = bg_color2
  end
end
```

`each_with_index` iterates through an array and provides a variable to track the current position within that array.